# SAS Macro loop that ends based on criteria

Tags: sql, loops, sas, sas-macro

I'm writing in SAS & primarily use proc sql for data cleaning.

I have a bit of code where I sequentially pull out records (ids) from a table . I want the code to loop until the table  is depleted. I wrote out this macro called catalina. I want it to run until the count variable I make on the final line of the macro is = to 0.

```
%macro catalina;  
proc sql;  
create table todelete as select max(id_todelete) as id_todelete from ids group by id_todelete;  
delete from pairs where id_a = any(select id_todelete from todelete);  
delete from pairs where id_b = any(select id_todelete from todelete);  
insert into matched select * from pairs where match_dist = (select min(match_dist) from pairs);  
insert into ids (id_todelete) select id_a from matched;  
insert into ids (id_todelete) select id_b from matched;  
select count(*) as count from pairs;  
%mend;
```

pin is my unique lookup value.
My  table houses the pins I want to sequentially remove from my parent table  until that  table is down to 0.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The first query is a little ambiguous.  Which values do you want it to group by?  The input variable pin_todelete? Or the output variable also named pin_todelete?

Comment: Thx! My pairs table has matches that were made matching pin_a to pin_b. The pins are unique, but I have multi matches and duplicate pins throughout both columns & pins in pin_a also appear in pin_b. I am trying to find the "best matches" based on minimizing the match_dist variable in the pairs table. Once I "find the best match" I want to remove it and populate it in the matched table. I then want to remove the pins involved in that match from the pairs table (columns: pin_a and pin_b) so that those pins won't be selected again as a match. I want to do this until the pairs table is depleted.

Comment: How large are the table `pins` and `pairs` ?  You would probably get a **much, much** faster processing rate using a DATA Step and hash component objects or arrays.

Comment: The pairs table has 8 million records and then the pins table is where I'm keeping track of  the pins (variables) that I'm removing from the pairs table after I've selected their "best match". I'll try to think about a DATA step. Harsh components objects and arrays are new for me. I'm more familiar with sql, so my go to is always proc sql. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the macro generate multiple blocks of code you need some macro logic.  Looks like you need a simple %DO %UNTIL() construct.  Note that you will need to create an actual macro variable in the last step and not just print the result to the output destination like your current code.  Are you positive your process will always get to zero obs?  If not then add more logic to stop after some fixed number of steps.  Or perhaps stop based on some other criteria that will always occur, like zero observations detected to be removed.

So put the parts that don't repeat before or after the %DO loop.

```
%macro catalina;
%local count ;
%let count=-1;
proc sql;
%do %until(&count <= 0);
  create table todelete as 
    select max(pin_todelete) as pin_todelete from pins group by pin_todelete
  ;
  delete from pairs where pin_a = any(select pin_todelete from todelete);
  delete from pairs where pin_b = any(select pin_todelete from todelete);
  insert into matched 
     select * from pairs 
     where match_dist = (select min(match_dist) from pairs)
  ;
  insert into pins (pin_todelete) select pin_a from matched;
  insert into pins (pin_todelete) select pin_b from matched;
  select count(*) format=32. into :count trimmed from pairs;
%end;
quit;
%mend;
```

If you explain more about what the algorithm is doing you might get an answer that shows an easier way to do it.

Comment: Thank you! I think this might work for me if I tweak the stop criteria a bit. I'm not 100% sure that it will actually run to zero like you said. I'm also new to macros, so could spend some time really learning the %DO %UNTIL(). This really helps me think about it thought. Much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The above worked! I just needed to take out the 3rd line you had and it ran perfectly. Takes some time - so I'm going to see if I can't do it with a DATA step as well. Much appreciated :)

If you know how I can mark it as a solution - please let me know. I'm new here, but would like to give the answer that credit.